# select outer and child ,without inner div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">
  <div class="child">

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to select outer and child only. But selecting outer will include inner and child. If I used `not` ie `$(".outer , .child").not(".inner")`, it will exclude child too.

ie **I want to select outer and child ,without inner**.

Comment: Surely this isn't possible, due to the HTML structure? Selecting `outer`, WILL ALWAYS include `Inner`?

Comment: But we can select `$(".outer").not(".inner")` which won't include inner after selection.

Comment: why can't you select both separately, just an idea.

Comment: Actually I want to know if there is any method opposite to `not` in jQuery. So that i can Include

Comment: what do you want to do with this selection?

Comment: Surely an opposite to not would be to not use the `:not`?

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar I want something like this, `$(".outer").not(".inner").but(".child");`

Comment: You can't - It's not as straight forward as that.. 

You would see to select the child, and then select outer and remove inner (i'll post an answer)

Comment: Inner is contained within Outer, so selecting Inner will return Inner, it's part of the DOM

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar No, the not method of jQuery could made it possible. We can select outer without inner even if inner included in outer. Which means  this is not impossible. rite?

Comment: @SubinJacob selecting outer means selecting inner too

Comment: Well forgive my saying so, but if what you say is right? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I've added an answer - it's not a simple query, but as is, you can't run a single query for it.

Answer (score 1):

As you can't select it perfectly using a single query, you'd be better taking it out of the DOM (You can't get the results you want `as is`)

```
//So clone it it from the dom
var outer = $('.outer').clone();
var child = $('child').clone();

// Remove the `Inner` from the cloned version
outer.find('.inner').detach();

// Add the child to the outer.
outer.append(child);
```

Comment: use `detach` instead of `remove`.\

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('.outer, .outer :not(.inner)')
```

Comment: outer includes inner too

Answer (score 0):

just use `.outer,.child`:

```
$('.outer,.child')
```

Comment: what do you mean by that. you select any node then it selects its inner dom structure too.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
$('.outer .child').not('.inner .child');
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vmPM3/)

Or, how about using this:

```
$('.outer > .child')
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vmPM3/1/)

Or, are you referring like this:

```
$('.outer, .outer .child').not('.inner .child');
```

Comment: Hey @C-link you selector wont work.You are only selecting `.child` of `.outer` OP wants to select outer and inner

Comment: No ..check ***I want to select outer and child ,without inner.***

Comment: @C-link No, this is not I wanted

Comment: I want to select outer div. But not inner div. If I use outer not inner, it will also remove child